# gRPC bidirectional function returns RequestType instead of ResponseType

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm learning gRPC using the official doc, but found the method signature of client-streaming and bidirectional-streaming very confusing (the two are the same).

From the doc [here](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/generated-code/#bidirectional-streaming), the function takes `StreamObserver<ResponseType>` as the input parameter and returns a `StreamObserver<ResponseType>` instance, as the following:

```
public StreamObserver<RequestType> bidirectionalStreamingExample(
    StreamObserver<ResponseType> responseObserver)
```

But in my mind, it should take the `RequestType` type as input and returns the `ResponseType` type:

```
public StreamObserver<ResponseType> bidirectionalStreamingExample(
    StreamObserver<RequestType> responseObserver)
```

This confuses me very much and I'm actually a little surprised that the answer didn't prompt up when I search is in google, I thought many people would have the same question. Am I missing something obvious here? Why would gRPC defines the signature like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion probably stems from being used to REST or non-streaming frameworks, where request-response is often mapped to a function's parameter-return. The paradigm shift here is that you're no longer supplying request-response, but rather *channels* to drop requests and responses. If you've studied C or C++, it's very much like going from

```
int get_square_root(int input);
```

to

```
void get_square_root(int input, int& output);
```

See how `output`'s now a *parameter*? But in case that makes no sense at all (my fault :-) here's a more organic path:

#### Server Streaming

Let's start with the **server streaming stub**, even if your eventual goal is client streaming.

```
public void serverStreamingExample(
    RequestType request,
    StreamObserver<ResponseType> responseObserver)
```

Q: Why is the "response" in the parameter list? A: It's not the *response* that's in the parameter list, but rather a *channel* to feed the eventual response to. So for example:

```
public void serverStreamingExample(
    RequestType request,
    StreamObserver<ResponseType> responseObserver) {
  
  ResponseType response = processRequest(request);

  responseObserver.onNext(response); // this is the "return"
  responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
```

Why? Because, the point of **streaming** is to keep alive a *channel* on which responses can keep flowing through. If you could only return 1 response and that's that, the function's done, then that's not a stream. By supplying a *channel*, you as the developer can choose to pass it along as needed, feeding it as many responses as you'd like via `onNext()` until you're satisfied and call `onCompleted()`.

#### Client Streaming

Now, let's move on to the client streaming stub:

```
public StreamObserver<RequestType> clientStreamingExample(
    StreamObserver<ResponseType> responseObserver)
```

Q: Wait, what! We know why the *response* is in the parameter list now, but how does it make sense to return a *request*? A: Again, we're not actually returning a *request*, but a *channel* for the client to drop requests! Why? Because the point of **client streaming** is to allow the client to supply requests *in pieces*. It can't do that with a single, traditional call to the server. So here's one way this can be implemented:

```
class ClientStreamingExample {

  int piecesRcvd = 0;

  public StreamObserver<RequestType> myClientStreamingEndpoint(
      StreamObserver<ResponseType> responseObserver) {

    return new StreamObserver<RequestType>() {

      @Override
      public void onNext(RequestType requestPiece) {
        // do whatever you want with the request pieces
        piecesRcvd++;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCompleted() {
        // when the client says they're done sending request pieces,
        // send them a response back (but you don't have to! or it can
        // be conditional!)
        ResponseType response =
            new ResponseType("received " + piecesRcvd + " pieces");
        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
        piecesRcvd = 0;
      }

      @Override
      public void onError() {
        piecesRcvd = 0;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

You might have to spend a little time studying this to fully understand, but basically, since the client may now send a stream of requests, you have to define *handlers* for each request piece, as well as handlers for the client saying it's done or errored out. (In my example, I have the server only respond when the client says it's done, but you're free to do anything you want. You can even have the server respond even *before* the client says it's done or not respond at all.)

#### Bidirectional Streaming

*This isn't really a thing!* :-) What I mean is, tutorials just mean to point out that nothing's stopping you from implementing exactly the above, just on *both sides*. So you end up with 2 applications that send and receive requests in pieces, and send and receive responses. They call this setup **bidirectional streaming**, and they're correct to, but it's just a little misleading since it's not doing anything technically different from client streaming. That's exactly why the signatures are the same. IMHO, tutorials should just mention a note like I have here, rather than repeat the stub.

#### Optional: Just for "fun"...

We began with the C++ analogy of going from

```
int get_square_root(int input); // "traditional" request-response
```

to

```
void get_square_root(int input, int& output); // server streaming
```

Do we want to carry on this analogy? Of course we do.

*Hello,* <sup>C++ function pointers</sup>*, my old friend...*

```
void (*fnPtr)(int) get_square_root_fn(int& output); // client streaming
```

And a demonstration of its use(lessness):

```
int main() { // aka the client
  int result;
  void (*fnPtr)(int) = server.get_square_root_fn(result);
  fnPtr(2);
  std::cout << result << std::endl; // 1.4142 assuming the fn actually does sqrt
}
```

Comment: This is crystal clear! I started to get this after going through the code examples on how it's used, thank you :)

Comment: Cool, I figured you would too once you dove into it. I wrote it out anyway for people who (and I'm one of them) like to read a lot before getting their hands dirty. Because for example, maybe we're just surveying some new tech. I guess maybe the lesson here is, we should just get our hands dirty.